# Visual Studio 2015 datagridview to excel seems to skip 2 rows. what is wrong with the code?

Tags: excel, vb.net, winforms, datagridview, export

Title says it all. Also got the code from microsoft. It skips the first row after the header and the last row but it successfully exported to excel.

```
Dim excel As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application()
        Dim workbook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook = excel.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing)
        Dim worksheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet = Nothing

        Try

            worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet

            worksheet.Name = "ExportedFromDatGrid"

            Dim cellRowIndex As Integer = 1
            Dim cellColumnIndex As Integer = 1

            'Loop through each row and read value from each column.
            For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2
                For j As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1
                    ' Excel index starts from 1,1. As first Row would have the Column headers, adding a condition check.
                    If cellRowIndex = 1 Then
                        worksheet.Cells(cellRowIndex, cellColumnIndex) = DataGridView1.Columns(j).HeaderText
                    Else
                        worksheet.Cells(cellRowIndex, cellColumnIndex) = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value.ToString()
                    End If
                    cellColumnIndex += 1
                Next
                cellColumnIndex = 1
                cellRowIndex += 1
            Next

            'Getting the location and file name of the excel to save from user.
            Dim saveDialog As New SaveFileDialog()
            saveDialog.Filter = "Excel files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx|All files (*.*)|*.*"
            saveDialog.FilterIndex = 2

            If saveDialog.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
                workbook.SaveAs(saveDialog.FileName)
                MessageBox.Show("Export Successful")
            End If
        Catch ex As System.Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Finally
            excel.Quit()
            workbook = Nothing
            excel = Nothing
        End Try
```

Thanks for the help! It is very much appreciated. I have nothing more to say. Please let me post my question stack.

Comment: Did you set a breakpoint and step through the code? If not then you need to do so. In doing so, you'll discover where in the code it's behaviour does not match your expectations. If you don't then it means that your expectations are wrong in the first place.

Comment: got it, since the value of cellrowindex = 1. it writes up the headers and on the cellrowindex = 2. it starts on the 2nd row and skips the first one. and for the last row that it skips. i just changed dgv.rows.count -2 to dgv.rows.count -1

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is is responsible for that problem (as you wrote in your comment)  .
why not to write it more readable and less clumsy?

here is my suggestion:

```
Dim excel As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application()
Dim workbook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook = excel.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing)
Dim worksheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet = Nothing

Try

    worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet

    worksheet.Name = "ExportedFromDatGrid"


    For cellColumnIndex = 0 To dgv.Columns.Count - 1
        worksheet.Cells(1, cellColumnIndex + 1) = dgv.Columns(cellColumnIndex).HeaderText
        For cellRowIndex = 0 To dgv.RowCount - 1
            worksheet.Cells(cellRowIndex + 2, cellColumnIndex + 1) = dgv.Rows(cellRowIndex).Cells(cellColumnIndex).Value
        Next
    Next


    worksheet.Rows("1:10000").RowHeight = 25
    'Getting the location and file name of the excel to save from user.
    Dim saveDialog As New SaveFileDialog()
    saveDialog.Filter = "Excel files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx|All files (*.*)|*.*"
    saveDialog.FilterIndex = 2

    If saveDialog.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        workbook.SaveAs(saveDialog.FileName)
        MessageBox.Show("Export Successful")
    End If
Catch ex As System.Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
Finally
    excel.Quit()
    workbook = Nothing
    excel = Nothing
End Try
```